# How to prevent deletion of cell content in online Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

an office clerk asked me if there would be a way to prevent deletion of a cell in online Excel. (Ms Office running from her workstation). I have no clue but the question appears interesting.

**Context**: she briefly publishes an adress where employees are required to write down their availabilities on different days. 
The login / password is the same for all employees.
The process is competitive but must follow certain rules, meaning each employee can write his/her name in front of the days he/she would like to work, for a maximum of 8 times.

**Problems**:

1. The server cannot cope with 15-20 people using the same
   login/password pair. Even though bandwidth is adequate, CPU
   power clearly isn't.
2. Some employees don't follow the rules: while
   many will limit themselves to the allowed 8 slots, a few others will happily delete their colleagues' names, filling 15 to 20 slots.

**Question**:
Would there be a way for her to configure the Excel spreadsheet so the 8 slots per person rule is enforced without the need for her to manually delete the offenders names?

Is it a matter of locking down the cell on the first name entered (Is that even possible?)
Is there a way for Excel to only allow a certain name to be written 8 times?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data Validation to do this.  Look under Data > Data Validation.

Data Validation is normally meant for more mundane tasks, like ensuring the entered value is a number, but you can also set it to use a custom formula.  Enter [`COUNTIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34):

> In its simplest form, COUNTIF says:
>   =COUNTIF(Where do you want to look?, What do you want to look for?)

(I love this, straight from MS documentation)

Let's use some sample data:
[image: Excel sample data]

When we set up `COUNTIF` we need to apply it to the range of cells that the users can enter text in (note this may not be a contiguous range, you can do `B2:B6:D2:D6` for example, but for simplicity I'm just blanketing the whole sheet).
*Note that it will need to be an absolute reference (`$B$2:$D$6`).*

The next part of `COUNTIF` is not completely intuitive, you need to set the "What do you want to look for?" to the currently selected cell in the data-validation block.  This is because that cell reference will change as the validation rule applies to each cell (it's the same reason the `COUNTIF` range needs to be absolute).

So it looks like this:
[image: Excel data validation entry]

*Note: If you change the data validation rule, it will only apply to the single cell selected.  Ensure you check the box `Apply these changes to all other cells with the same settings`*

You need to keep `Ignore blank` checked, else it will count blank cells and invalidate them.  You can also do some fun stuff like customise the error alert.  When it's all working, it looks like this:
[image: Excel data validation]

Answer (score 0):

I believe one method would be to enable tracking history.

That way you can open the file tomorrow and see what each person has done.
If one person has deleted a college then it will show up in the tracking history.

This is a "low budget" fix and will only show when someone has deleted "Jane" and replaced it with "Mary".
This can also be disabled by someone knowing that it's on and/or someone who wants to replace "Jane".

---

Another more complex solution is VBA.
I have made a workbook where you need to log in to edit it, and once logged in you could use VBA code that runs each time a cell is changed.
This change can then be written to a separate sheet or workbook.
In the same VBA code you can also make it look for how many times the same name appears.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the solution provided by Ian in Excel 2016 (Mac), but it doesn't do anything… No popup or anything like that.